# Page numbers vanish when margins are altered

Tags: header-footer

I am generating a LaTeX document where there must be 1 inch margins all around.

However, this seems to make the page numbers vanish (i.e., they appear outside of footer)

I have tried several things to solve the problem, but page numbers are still absent. These solutions include:

(1) placing

```
includefoot
```

within the specification for the 'geometry' package

(2) using the command

```
\setlength{\footskip}{20pt}
```

to decrease the footskip.

Below is my code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in, top=1in,bottom=1in, includefoot]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{fancyhdr,etoolbox}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\fancyhead[OL]{\ifnumodd{\value{page}}{Lorem ipsum}{Lorem ipsum} 

\setlength{\footskip}{20pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Any idea on how to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\fancyhf{}` clear all header and footer fields. To print page numbers in footer (again), you can use, for example `\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}`.

Comment: Thanks! It worked perfectly.